# Format disk with diskpart if not formatted

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, diskpart

I'm trying to write a script to create and format a partition in Windows Server 2008R2.

Now, when `disk 1` is selected, I need to format it, *only if it is **not** formatted already*. This is what I have now:

Run: `diskpart /s script.txt`

Content of `script.txt`

```
select disk 1
clean
create partition primary
format fs=ntfs unit=65536 quick
active
assign letter=D
```

Any help?

Comment: You should be using Powershell as opposed to using DOS commands, Powershell allows for greater flexibility and will allow you to evaluate if a disk is not formatted then perform an action on it if the statement equals true. I assume you already know this though as you added a "Powershell" tag into your post. In any case, this command should get you started "Get-Command *disk*"

Comment: You are right, the problem its that in Windows 2008R2 there are no Storage Cmdlets in Windows PowerShell.

Comment: Those diskpart replacements are only for v4 powershell and above.  But don't worry, we can still check drive formatted status via Get-WmiObject cmdlet.  Also look into the `Win32_Volume Format` method to avoid diskpart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me.

```
foreach ($disk in get-wmiobject Win32_DiskDrive -Filter "Partitions = 0"){ 
   $disk.DeviceID
   $disk.Index
   "select disk "+$disk.Index+"`r clean`r create partition primary`r format fs=ntfs unit=65536 quick`r active`r assign letter=D" | diskpart
}
```

In this case, i get the disk with NO partitions, and then i create a D drive with all available space

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while back using here strings to format the complete diskpart commands.  It's a bit goofy looking but it worked at the time when we were trying to automate this quickly for a high number of luns on multi node clusters.  the WMI method is definitely cleaner looking.